# How to retrieve all lines from a text parameter in a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a text parameter in my jenkinsFile used by a Jenkins pipeline job. This text parameter is used to enter a list of filenames (one per line).

Strangely only value on the first line of the text field seems to be detected when I print out build environment variables.

**jenkinsFile**

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        
        parameters {
            
            text(
                    name: 'FILE_LIST', 
                    defaultValue: '', 
                    description: 'File list'
            )
        }
        
        stages {

            stage("Environnement variables") {
                steps {
                    sh 'printenv | grep FILE_LIST'
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**Content example for text field**

```
test.sql
MY_TEST.SQL
test_01.sql
```

**Result**

```
FILE_LIST=test.sql
```

How to access values of all lines from a text parameter within a Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if  you want to get something like this "printenv | grep file1 file2 " use the below code

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    parameters {
        
        text(
                name: 'FILE_LIST', 
                defaultValue: '', 
                description: 'File list'
        )
    }
    
    stages {

        stage("Environnement variables") {
            steps {
                script{
                    String fllist=FILE_LIST.split("\r?\n").join(' ')
                    echo fllist
                     
                    sh 'printenv | grep $fllist'
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Just one caveat, $fllist variable is not available in sh 'printenv | grep $fllist' context. I tried to echo $fllist and it is blank... Any idea why?

Comment: sh command needs to be double quoted as: sh "printenv | grep $fllist" and then it is possible to access "fllist" variable value from sh directive